# Problem using calender extender ajax control

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I am not able to see calender in my webpage even when i have added calenderextender to the textbox control in my webpage.

Here is my code .aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CR" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From Date"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="fromdatetextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="fromdatetextbox_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="fromdatetextbox">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
        <br />
        <br />
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True"
            Height="500px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" Width="500px" />
        <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
            <Report FileName="CrystalReport1.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR:CrystalReportSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to sortout what am i doing wrong. I want to display calender on textbox being highlighted i.e if a user clicks inside the textbox,calender must appear.

Comment: can you just comment that crystalreportviewer and then please check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Instead of

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

and it worked. was it the real problem? as i have seen many examples on different forum that use scripmanager n still it works for them

Comment: "was it the real problem? " yes. The ScriptManager is the **old way** of doing it, this is why have seen so many examples; they are outdated. The ToolkitScriptManager inherits from ScriptManager and add some optimizations for the controls of the toolkit.